# Moment.js display hour in local format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I guess this is quite simple question, but I am currently unable to find it in [moment's documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). I have to display just an hour in local format, e.g.

- for locale `en-gb`: 14
- for locale `en-us`: 2 PM

The closest format I've found is `LT`, but it also displays minutes that are not desired...

Here is what I tried:

```
moment().format('LT'); // 14:00 / 2:00 PM
// I need some kind of combination of these two:
moment().format('H'); // 14
moment().format('h A'); // 2 PM
```

Is there a moment-way to achieve it or am I forced to use a work-around like below?

```
moment().format('LT').replace(/:[0-9]{2}/, '');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in method in momentjs 2.18.1 to get the localized input you are looking for. The [localized formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) availables that include time are:

```
Time                                               | LT    | 8:30 PM
Time with seconds                                  | LTS   | 8:30:25 PM
Month name, day of month, day of week, year, time  | LLLL  | Thursday, September 4 1986 8:30 PM
                                                   | llll  | Thu, Sep 4 1986 8:30 PM
```

So you probably have to use a work around like you showed in the question. The following script creates and displays a Map with the number of occurences for each `LT` string. It uses [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat` to get localized format for `LT`.

```js
let formatMap = new Map();

['af' , 'ar-dz', 'ar-kw', 'ar-ly', 'ar-ma', 'ar-sa', 'ar-tn', 'ar', 'az', 'be', 'bg', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'ca', 'cs', 'cv', 'cy', 'da', 'de-at', 'de-ch', 'de', 'dv', 'el', 'en-au', 'en-ca', 'en-gb', 'en-ie', 'en-nz', 'eo', 'es-do', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fi', 'fo', 'fr-ca', 'fr-ch', 'fr', 'fy', 'gd', 'gl', 'gom-latn', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hu', 'hy-am', 'id', 'is', 'it', 'ja', 'jv', 'ka', 'kk', 'km', 'kn', 'ko', 'ky', 'lb', 'lo', 'lt', 'lv', 'me', 'mi', 'mk', 'ml', 'mr', 'ms-my', 'ms', 'my', 'nb', 'ne', 'nl-be', 'nl', 'nn', 'pa-in', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'pt', 'ro', 'ru', 'sd', 'se', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'sq', 'sr-cyrl', 'sr', 'ss', 'sv', 'sw', 'ta', 'te', 'tet', 'th', 'tl-ph', 'tlh', 'tr', 'tzl', 'tzm-latn', 'tzm', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz-latn', 'uz', 'vi', 'x-pseudo', 'yo', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'zh-tw'].forEach(localeName => {
  var format =  moment.localeData(localeName).longDateFormat('LT');
  
  if( formatMap.has(format) ){
    let val = formatMap.get(format);
    formatMap.set(format, val+1);
  } else {
    formatMap.set(format, 1);
  }
  
});

console.log(formatMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Note that breton (`br`) locale uses `h[e]mm A` format and there are 7 locales (including: German (Switzerland) `de-ch`, Finnish `fi`, Indonesian `id`, etc) that use `HH.mm`.

Those cases are not covered by your workaround, maybe you can use something like:

```
moment().format('LT').replace(/(:|\.)[0-9]{2}/, '');
```

or

```
moment().format('LT').replace(/(:|\.|e)[0-9]{2}/, '');
```

to get the desired output for these locales.

Comment: Thanks! That should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use moment.locale API to create your custom format
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/

Comment: This way I'd have to customize every language I'm going to use, haven't I?

Comment: yes, just set locale you want to use, and the other set by default moment api.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `moment().format('hh');`returns hours in  double digit like 09,10.If you want a single digit use `moment().format('h');` this will print just 2,3,...When you want to print hours with meridiem use `moment().format('hh a');` and `moment().format('h a');` these both prints meridiem in small letters.You can use `moment().format('hh A');` and `moment().format('h a');` for representing meridiem in capital letters.This way you can  print hours in local format .Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Not really, I mentioned these options in my questions and said they don't meet my needs. I want a format like `LT` to display just an hour in local time, like `10` or `10 AM`, `20` or `8 PM` etc...

Comment: I understood what you need.These meets your requirement.I used in my code .You can check these syntaxes in repl terminal it returns the value you want.And onething it returns the present time.

Comment: I mentioning another time use moment().format('h A'); This will definetly work.

Comment: Please give me one format string that will return only hour in local format... Local format is the key here, I'm looking for a dynamic solution, just like the work-around provided in the question.

Comment: Why you want to use Local format ?using local formats will give minutes also see these  LT: 'HH:mm',
    L: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    LL: 'D MMMM YYYY',
    LLL: 'D MMMM YYYY LT',
    LLLL: 'dddd D MMMM YYYY LT' as your requirement is printing hours with meridiem then use the syntaxes what I mentioned earlier

Comment: @Daniel Kucal just try this moment().format('LT A').replace(/:[0-9]{2}/, ''); let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: `moment().format('LT').replace(/:[0-9]{2}/, '');` works for me, this is the work-around I gave in the question, stop trolling me ( ◔ ʖ̯ ◔ )

Comment: Have you notice I added meridiem to that syntax and now it doesn't printing minutes.

Comment: Sure. Have you noticed it will return e.g. `7 AM AM` for `moment.locale('en-us')`?

Comment: I know how to achieve what I want and I did it, but this is a work-around. My  question is actually about solution provided by `moment` library, please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can be done by moment.js local API as [Rahmat Aligos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366525/rahmat-aligos) suggested.

Looking at their website functionality here is the code snippet that will do the needful.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-locale]', function() {
  var dom = $(this);
  currentLang = dom.data('locale');
  $('[data-locale]').removeClass('active');
  dom.addClass('active');
  updateSnippets();
});

function updateSnippets() {
  var i;

  moment.locale(currentLang); // si or en-gb or tzm-latn etc..

  for (i = 0; i < snippets.length; i++) {
    snippets[i].update();
  }
}
```

Notice they set selected country in moment.locale(currentLang) section.
Ex: If you select *Arabic (Kuwait)* then output will be:

*moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // غشت 9 2017, 9:31:00 am*

If you want to detect the browser language to set the moment.js local then use this following code:

```js
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

console.log(language); //works IE/SAFARI/CHROME/FF
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question... It's not about how to set a locale or update already generated instances of `moment`... I'm just looking for a format to display only the hour, just like `LT` displays hour with minutes.

Comment: Aah.. I see. Sorry my bad though. :)