# Time (hour, minute) format localization in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

As momentjs has the ability take into account the date format for differernt locales, does it have the ability to localize time (hour:minute) format?

According to oracle docs time format there're some time format difference across region
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-6/index.html

moment().locale(somelocale).format('L') this will output the formatted date

However

moment().locale(somelocale).format('LT') doesn't seem like to have the same ability?

```
class TimeFormatter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const browserLocale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    return (
      <div>
        {moment(this.props.value, 'HH:mm').locale(browserLocale).format('LT')}
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Above is my code for formatting the time cell on react data grid, but while I change the chrome settings the format stays the same.

So if I want to achieve time format localization can I use momentjs or I have to just come up a if else condition for setup specific user region time format

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js display hour in local format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580978/moment-js-display-hour-in-local-format)

Comment: Why do you think `LT` doesn't have the same ability?  That's what it is for. Please give an example if you're not getting what you expect.

Comment: The format I indicating 23:59  vs 23.59  vs 23.59 Uhr  ... as the oracle link shown

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, I have more details revised, take into account the current code I have, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LT` format *does* take locale into account.

Here are some examples:

```
moment().locale('en-CA').format('LT') //=> "1:21 PM"
moment().locale('fr-CA').format('LT') //=> "13:21"
moment().locale('fi-FI').format('LT') //=> "13.21"
moment().locale('de-DE').format('LT') //=> "13:21"
moment().locale('no-NO').format('LT') //=> "1:21 PM"
moment().locale('th-TH').format('LT') //=> "13:21"
moment().locale('en-GB').format('LT') //=> "13:21"
```

Note that the Oracle page you linked to is part of the Solaris 8 documentation - an operating system which came out in February 2000 and reached end of life in March 2012.  It is sorely mistaken with regard to the time formats used in those countries and languages.  You should not use it as a reference.

Also note that that it made a grave error in assuming that "Canadian" was enough to identify a locale completely.  As shown above, French speaking Canadians use a 24-hour clock, but many English speaking Canadians sometimes use a 12-hour clock (see [Time notation in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Canada#Time_notation)) and thus `en-CA` gives the 12-hour format while `fr-CA` gives the 24-hour format.

Thus, country alone is not enough.  A locale must consist of at least language, but usually both language and country are necessary.  These are now called ["IETF language tags"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) and are standardized by [BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47).

As far as why Moment's German localization doesn't include the string `Uhr` in the result, that was something that was first added with [#1601](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1601), but then removed with [#2006](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2006) - both back in 2014.  See those issues for reasoning.

Also note that Moment's localization strings come from community submitted feedback and moment contributors.  In many cases they align to the standards collated by [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), but in some cases they differ.  If you are looking for a modern date library with *standardized* localization support, consider [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) which leverages the internationalization APIs built into modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I was asking because my date localization is working but not the time. Is there any issue on my code transferring 'HH:mm' to localized time? I think that is my problem more specifically

Comment: Well based on your edit (which changes the question significantly), I think you're perhaps just expecting your render function to fire when Chrome settings change - which it won't do automatically.  You should be able to see the change in `window.navigator.language` after reloading though.

Comment: It works, just I found nowadays the time format is less difference, thank you for the detailed answer again

Comment: It's not working for me. When I cut and paste that code, I get "1:10 PM" for every one.